# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown determine what element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a following code:

```
<div id="dropdown" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I am clicking on some link. How can I determine what link is clicked?

```
$("#dropdown").click(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  //how?? 
});
```

I am also using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu > li > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Disable href
    window.alert($(this).text()); //$(this).text() is what you want
});
```

Update: [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/34m2c/)